# How to recover type of list element in r?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

The code below complains with:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :    no applicable method for 'predict'
>   applied to an object of class "list"
>   >

Is there any way to cast the list element back to the correct type?

edit: thanks to @李哲源, the code immediately below does work:

```
models <- list(m, logit, loglog)
plot(x,y)
abline(models[[1]],col="black",lty=2)
lines(x,predict(models[[2]], df),col="red",lty=3)
```

original code:

```
if(!require(betareg)){install.packages("betareg")}
set.seed(123)
x=seq(1,9,1)
print(x)
y=x/10+0+rnorm(length(x),0,.1)
print(y)
m=lm(y~x)
logit<-betareg(y~x,na.action=na.omit)
plot(x,y)
abline(m,col="red",lty=2)
#lines(x,predict(logit, y),col="green",lty=3)
models=c(m,logit)
abline(models[1],col="blue",lty=4)
lines(x,predict(models[2], y),col="blue",lty=5)
```

Comment: I'd approach this in a "tidy" fashion by storing the data and the models in a data frame, then using tools such as `dplyr` and `broom`. See [this presentation](http://ijlyttle.github.io/isugg_purrr/presentation.html#(1)) for example. Happy to post an answer on that if it helps.

Comment: @neilfws thanks for the offer, but  i am a newbie and did not know about the  [[ operator and i want to use basic r for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regression model is stored as a "list" with special "class". Direct concatenation using `c` drops such "class". Check `length(models)`: you have 41 not 2.

Use either of the following

```
models <- c(list(m), list(logit))
models <- list(m, logit)
```

to preserve "class" of regression models, and use `models[[1]]` and `models[[2]]` to access those models (for example, `abline(models[[1]])` and `predict(models[[2]], y)`).

Alternatively, set up a proper list beforehand and fill in (this is useful if you store models in a loop)

```
models <- vector("list", 2)
models[[1]] <- m
models[[2]] <- logit
```